SGID in File Permissions
the following are two scenarios to let you know how i understand the problem and the SGID:

Scenario 1:
user A is part of the group G.
group G has full privileges to 2 files-its the group owner of these files AND has rwx- in the system of user B where 1 file is a script the other file is a normal file which the script relies on to work.
now if user A is part of the group G this means that he also has the same privileges
his group has which means he can execute these 2 files successfully.

Scenario 2:
user B doesnt want any USER on the system to have any access to his file that the script relies on but he wants the users to be able to run the script so he decided to use setgid on the executable file and remove user A from the group G so he wont have direct access to the file yet still be able to run the executable with the help of the sgid.


I wonder if its possible, and is this how setgid works?

Linux famously ignores setuid and setgid on scripts, so you'd at least need to make an binary executable wrapper for your script.

so then whats the use of setgid(i know how it works on directories) but i mean on a normal executable, even whats the purpose of suid if linux ignores it on scripts, because i know that its main purpose is related to scripts and being able to execute something without having permission to see something else like the passwd command for example

You use it on executables other than scripts, e.g., compiled C, C++, Go programs, etc. I don't know where you learnt that "its main purpose is related to scripts", but it definitely hasn't applied to the script files themselves in decades.

i have this py script import os try: with open('/home/user/file','r') as f:           print(f.read()) except Exception as e: print(f"an error has occured:{e}") -the syntax is of course not like this in the file - anyways the idea is that i want the user to be able to execute this without being able to read /home/user/file. so now i can conclude that sdig or suid wont allow me to do so ?(this is not the real program im working on but its just an example)

Yes. You can easily test such a script by checking the values returned by os.geteuid() and os.getegid()
